# How can I selectively trigger computations in Manipulate?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, random

I have a `Manipulate` that uses `RandomVariate` and `Random` that I would like to have redraw and recompute random values selectively, depending on what `Manipulate` parameters have been changed.

For example, I would like to be able to control redraws and recomputations so that

- new `data` and `honestMeans` are only computed if `n` has changed;
- new `punishMeans` are computed only when `n` or `punish` have changed;
- a redraw is triggered when `zoom` changes, but without triggering an update to `data`, `honestMeans`  or `punishMeans`;
- a redraw triggered when any of  `data`, `honestMeans`  or `punishMeans` or `zoom` changes (without triggering a recomputation of `data`, `honestMeans`  or `punishMeans`);
- everything updates if an explicit update is requested (somehow)

as indicated in the comments below:

```
scale = 5;
dist = HypergeometricDistribution[scale, Round[0.7*2*scale], 2*scale];
genVotes[punish_, n_] := Module[{},
   votes = {data[[1]]};
   For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
    If[Random[] < punish,
     If[votes[[i - 1]] > data[[i]], vote = 0, vote = scale],
     vote = data[[i]]
     ];
    AppendTo[votes, Mean[Append[data[[1 ;; i - 1]], vote]]];
    AppendTo[votes, Mean[Append[data[[1 ;; i - 1]], data[[i]]]]];
    ]; Return[votes];
   ];

Manipulate[
  data = RandomVariate[dist, n];(* Should only change when n changes *)
  punishMeans = genVotes[punish, n]; (* Should change when punish or n change *)
  honestMeans = genVotes[0, n]; (* Should only change when n changes *)
  GraphicsColumn[{ (* Should redraw when any of the above change, or if zoom changes, without triggering recompilation of data, punishMeans or honestMeans *)
   Show[
    ListPlot[punishMeans,
     Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> Gray, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {(1 - zoom)*#, (1 + zoom)*#} &[Mean[data]]},
     Frame -> True, Axes -> None,
     Epilog -> {Blue, Line[{{0, Mean[data]}, {n, Mean[data]}}]}],
    ListPlot[honestMeans,
     Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> None]
    ],
   Show[
    Histogram[data, scale, PlotRange -> {{0, scale + 1}, All}, 
     Frame -> True,
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
        Automatic}, {{# + .5, #, 0} & /@ Range[0, scale], None}}, 
     Axes -> None],
    DiscretePlot[n*PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, scale + 1}, Joined -> True, 
     PlotMarkers -> None, Filling -> None]
    ]
   }],
 {{n, 100}, 10, 5000},
 {{punish, 0.5}, 0, 1},
 Delimiter,
 {{zoom, 0.2}, .1, .5},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n, punish, zoom}]
```

Is there a way to do this kind of selective update of elements of a `Manipulate`?

Comment: Please don't post your full-blown code/problem  here but just a minimal example for other users to work with.

Comment: @belisarius: That's my MWE. (All interdependencies matter, as near as I can tell.) Don't hesitate to simplify the example if you spot an opportunity to do so.

Comment: fyi, your code above does not run, it has errors in it, on V 9.01 , here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QXSFr.png)  may be if you fix these first it will help.

Comment: @Nasser: Thanks. Fixed (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the second argument of dynamics, which acts like an event call back. In there, you do the specific action needed when that dynamic changes. This localizes the logic with its own control variable. Makes it easier to manage. If you like more information about this method, see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40066/how-to-avoid-an-expensive-subset-of-a-manipulate-computation-when-dependent-vari)

But you really need to fix/improve the way the function `genVotes` works. It is very inefficient and slow (that is why I made `ContinuousAction -> False` below for now), and it also uses global `data` which is not a good way to implement it. I'll leave this for you to fix.

```
scale = 5;
dist = HypergeometricDistribution[scale, Round[0.7*2*scale], 2*scale];

genVotes[punish_, n_] := Module[{},
   votes = {data[[1]]};
   For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
    If[Random[] < punish,
     If[votes[[i - 1]] > data[[i]],
      vote = 0,
      vote = scale
      ],
     vote = data[[i]]
     ];
    AppendTo[votes, Mean[Append[data[[1 ;; i - 1]], vote]]];
    AppendTo[votes, Mean[Append[data[[1 ;; i - 1]], data[[i]]]]]
    ];
   votes
   ];

Manipulate[tick;

 GraphicsColumn[{

   Show[ListPlot[punishMeans, Joined -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> Gray, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {(1 - zoom)*#, (1 + zoom)*#} &[Mean[data]]}, 
     Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
     Epilog -> {Blue, Line[{{0, Mean[data]}, {n, Mean[data]}}]}], 
    ListPlot[honestMeans, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> None]
    ],

   Histogram[data, scale, PlotRange -> {{0, scale + 1}, All}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
      {{# + .5, #, 0} & /@ Range[0, scale], None}}, Axes -> None], 
   DiscretePlot[n*PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, scale + 1}, Joined -> True, 
      PlotMarkers -> None, Filling -> None]
   }],

 Grid[{
   {"n",
    Manipulator[Dynamic[
      n, {n = #; data = RandomVariate[dist, n]; punishMeans = genVotes[punish, n]; 
        honestMeans = genVotes[0, n]; 
        tick = Not[tick]} &], {10, 200, 1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[n]
    },
   {"punish",
    Manipulator[Dynamic[punish, {punish = #; punishMeans = genVotes[punish, n]; 
     tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 1, 0.1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[punish]
    },
   {"zoom",
    Manipulator[Dynamic[zoom, {zoom = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {.1, .5, 0.1}, 
      ImageSize -> Tiny, ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic[zoom]
    }
   }
  ],

 {{zoom, .2}, None},
 {{n, 100}, None},
 {{punish, .5}, None},
 {{tick, False}, None},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, sorry: `genVotes` and the use of `data` are pretty terrible. I'll fix that.